# British Citizen, US Driving License, can I drive for 12 months in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

Okay so I moved to North America with my wife two years ago and learned to drive pretty much straight away.

I only have a provisional license in the UK as I gave up when I realized we were moving.

Now the question is on returning to the UK am I eligible to drive via my US license for 12 months or will I not be able to drive at all until I take my test?

I couldn't find anything relating to a situation like this so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official [uk.gov test](https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence). It is only 3 questions long, but a UK resident with a full license from "any other country" (essentially not the EU)

> You can drive in Great Britain on your full, valid driving licence for 12 months from when you became resident

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To me that sounds like I will become a UK resident when I return there in two weeks so I should be able to drive till June 2016 without a UK license. Their wording seems to also imply that is for 'new' residents and not someone who has lived in the UK prior to that however so may have to contact the DVLA directly.

Comment: @Hard-BoiledWonderland IANAL but if that was the case, I think they would have had a 4th question about if you had ever been a resident in the past. If you get pulled over a cop is not going to ask for your entire life history, I think it only will be a problem if you get into an accident and your insurance does not want to pay out.

Comment: Called them this morning to double check and you were right, thanks!